# Showing that $\vert{}\int_{\gamma}{f(x)}dx\vert\le\int_{\gamma}\vert f(x)\vert ds$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been struggling with the inequality $$\left\vert\int_{\gamma}{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x\right\vert\le\int_{\gamma}\vert f(x)\vert \mathrm{d}s,$$ where $f$ is continuous and $\gamma$ is of finite length. My problem is that $f$ could be multivarible function, which was defined in our course as $$\int_{\gamma}f(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\sum_{k=1}^{d}\int_{\gamma}f_k(x)\mathrm{d}x_k.$$

The definition says that $$\int_{\gamma}g(x)\mathrm{d}x_k=\lim_{\delta(P(I))\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N g(X(t^*_i))(X_k(t_i)-X_k(t_{i-1})),$$ and $$\int_{\gamma}h(x)ds=\lim_{\delta(P(I))\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N h(x(t^*_i))\vert X(t_i)-X(t_{i-1})\vert$$ where $\displaystyle\delta(P(I))=\max_{1\le i\le N}\{t_i-t_{i-1}\}$, and in this case $h(x)=\vert f(x) \vert(\Vert f(x)\Vert)$ (the notation in brackets rarely used by my Professor).

I tried raising both sides to the power of two, and it was so ugly-looking and unhelpful that I skipped detailing it here. So many factors in both sides were incomparable, and I believe this is the wrong approach. Also, trying to compare $\displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{k=1}^d\int_{a}^{b}f_k(X(t))|X_k'(t)|\mathrm{d}t\right\vert\le \int_{a}^{b}|f(X(t)||X'(t)|\mathrm{d}t$ led me at best to $\text{LHS}\le d\cdot \text{RHS}$. Could you please tell me where I got wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, rather than the weaker estimate you used.
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\gamma}f\cdot\,dx\right|&=\left|\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma’(t)\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_a^b|f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma’(t)|\,dt\\
&\leq\int_a^b\|f(\gamma(t))\|\cdot\|\gamma’(t)\|\,dt\\
&=\int_{\gamma}\|f\|\,ds
\end{align}
The first equality is just definition (with $\cdot$ being the usual dot/inner product of two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$). The second inequality is the familiar one: for any (Riemann or Lebesgue… doesn’t matter) integrable function $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$, $\left|\int_a^bg(t)\,dt\right|\leq\int_a^b|g(t)|\,dt$; here we are considering $g(t)=f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma’(t)$ (this is continuous, so integrable). The next inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz. The final one is by definition again.